How to protect connection string in an MVC application
I am currently using appsetting.json to read connection string and credentials with an MVC application.
I read something about this solution and it seems wrong.
How can I solve the problem?
Where should this information be stored?

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/connection-string-encryption-and-decryption/ba-p/830094

sorry for the delay and thanks for the solution. I used this option for my classic website in asp.net, but in MVC the connection string is in appsetteing.json, with other information. I can encrypt this file in some way?
